# Plotting values excluded by FunctionRange

Tags: plotting, functions

The following FunctionRange

```
(*a=((1-x) y)/(1-y z)*)
FunctionRange[{{((1 - x) y)/(1 - y z)}, 0 <= x <= 1, y > 1, 
   0 < z < 1}, {x}, a, Reals] // Simplify
```

returns

```
y > 1 && z < 1 && z > 0 && y z != 1 && a y z <= a && a <= y + a y z
```

I'm struggling to see how to illustrate/plot (in 2D or 3D) the values of `x, y, z` that are excluded and the resulting values for `a` that are excluded.

Appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: Maybe `result = 
  FunctionRange[{((1 - x) y)/(1 - y z), 0 <= x <= 1, y > 1, 
    0 < z < 1}, {x}, a, Reals];
Reduce[result, a]`

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. I've clarified the OP. What I meant by "illustrate the values" is some type of plot, 2D or 3D

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ((1 - x) y)/(1 - y z);
RegionPlot3D[
 y > 1 && z < 1 && z > 0 && y z != 1 && a y z <= a && a <= y + a y z,
 {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2},
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that led me to, what I believe is, the end result I was after.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the following is the program:

1. Calculate the `FunctionRange` in terms of the function `a` for one of the variables.
2. Use `Reduce` to obtain a form suitable for plotting (HT: @cvgmt)
3. Replace `a` to return to the original variables
4. Again `Reduce` and then
5. Plot **the complement** of the constraints using `RegionPlot3D` (HT: @david-p-stork)
6. Some sort of color scale to show the values of `a`...

```
(*step 1*)
result = 
 FunctionRange[{((1 - x) y)/(1 - y z), 0 <= x <= 1, y > 1, 
   0 < z < 1}, {x}, a, Reals]
(*step 2, 3 and 4*)
r = Reduce[Reduce[result, a] /. a -> ((1 - x) y)/(1 - y z)]
(*step 5*)
RegionPlot3D[! (0 < z < 
     1 && ((1 < y < 1/z && 0 <= x <= 1) || (y > 1/z && 
        0 <= x <= 1))), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 1, 10}, {z, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]